# Open file stored in SQLite as blob

Tags: android, sqlite, blob

As the title, I create a ByteArray to store the file in blob like this: 
`byte[] red_buf = myCursor.getBlob(1);`
And I wanna use FileOutputStream to open.
But I don't know how to do.
Can anyone give me a example or website please ??

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for may actually be [ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html), instead of FileOutputStream. That's just a guess because the question is very unclear

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the documentation, it looks like you could use getBinaryStream() to read the BLOB

documentation:  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html